# open links in iframe one by one when press button

Tags: javascript, php

i've a array of three links for a button which i'm using in footer and when i press the button again and again , array will work one by one good ..and every time it shows a link when press the button. That is good.
but i want , when i click on button that *"link" should open in "iframe"* ... i used iframe code to pass them src= button id but not working.. please below code and help..
.
my button code with array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script>
let link = new Array()
link[0] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL3+8QE&distance=20"
link[1] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL5+3NG&distance=20"
link[2] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL4+3NS&distance=20"

let intlinkIndex = 0;

function writeLink() {
  if (intlinkIndex >= link.length) {
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    mylink.style.display = 'none';
  }
    document.getElementById('mylink').innerHTML = '<a href="' + link[intlinkIndex] + '">' + link[intlinkIndex] + '</a>';
    intlinkIndex++;



}
</script>





</head>
<body>



<div class="footer"> 

<button id="btn" onclick="writeLink();">Click Me</button>

<div id="mylink"></div>

<br>


<iframe id="iframe" src="mylink" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by specifying iframe's name in `target` when generating link html.

So add a `name` property in your iframe like following:

```
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="mylink" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
```

Then add a `target` property.

```
document.getElementById('mylink').innerHTML = '<a href="' + link[intlinkIndex] + '" target="iframe">' + link[intlinkIndex] + '</a>';
```

```
function writeLink() {
    if (intlinkIndex >= link.length) {
      let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      btn.style.display = 'none';
      mylink.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('mylink').innerHTML = '<a href="' + link[intlinkIndex] + '">' + link[intlinkIndex] + '</a>';
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = link[intlinkIndex];
    intlinkIndex++;
  }
```

Full source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script>
let link = new Array()
link[0] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL3+8QE&distance=20"
link[1] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL5+3NG&distance=20"
link[2] = "https://www.clc-uk.org.uk/cms/cms.jsp?menu_id=26131&postcode=AL4+3NS&distance=20"

let intlinkIndex = 0;

function writeLink() {
  if (intlinkIndex >= link.length) {
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    mylink.style.display = 'none';
  }
    document.getElementById('mylink').innerHTML = '<a href="' + link[intlinkIndex] + '">' + link[intlinkIndex] + '</a>';
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = link[intlinkIndex];
    intlinkIndex++;
}
</script>





</head>
<body>



<div class="footer"> 

<button id="btn" onclick="writeLink();">Click Me</button>

<div id="mylink"></div>

<br>


<iframe id="iframe" src="mylink" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```